# Do Google Apps Scripts have a Copy URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm wondering if there is a way to share a link to a Google Apps Script file that forces users to make a copy of it? Using Google Docs, you can append /copy to the url. For example:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/19yoQ71RcqNsYgPmZHzw96G_QH05hC20sWxk_ktahpXY/copy

This will force users to make a copy of the original document. I've been trying to do something similiar with a Google Apps Script file.

I've tried appending copy to the URL like [this](https://script.google.com/a/edmonton.ca/d/17Da1E3Tg35kaEwpkQulaKTZg7o9AY0YK76E50D4xewdUf02Gqyd1_aXX/copy) but it doesn't seem to work. As a potential work around, I could just use embedded scripts and share the Sheet/Doc/Form.

Anyone know of a URL parameter to force copying of a Google Apps Script file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this format to quickly make a copy of any public Google Script.

https://script.google.com/d/SCRIPT_ID/edit?newcopy=true

See [example](https://script.google.com/d/17Da1E3Tg35kaEwpkQulaKTZg7o9AY0YK76E50D4xewdUf02Gqyd1_aXX/edit?newcopy=true).

Comment: This doesn't work with the new IDE interface that was just released

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this since the new editor has been rolled, have reported it on this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198266388

You can manually make a copy on the new editor by going to the "Overview" tab, and on the top-right is the button to make a copy.

[image]